# C++ - Trying to create a function that reads data from a file into an array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, visual-c++, struct

I've looked at a couple similar questions but I still can't seem to come close to understanding this. I get the basic idea for structs and array but I'm so lost for actually creating a function to read data from a file into an array of structs. Hoping someone could help me out. :(

We have to:

> 1. Write a function, InputPlayerData that will read the data from the input file of unknown >length into the array of structs
>
> A. The data in the input file contains the following information about each player
>
> > - name
> > - position
> > - number (Player's number on her jersey)
> > - at bats (The number of times a player is at bat)
> > - hits (The number of hits while at bat)
> > - bases taken (The number of bases run after a hit)
>
> B. Sample lines of data from the input file:
>
> i. The data for the first player:
>
> > - **MarTee Apple** is the player’s name
> > - **Catcher** is the player’s position
> > - **17** is her jersey number
> > - **20** is the number of times at bat
> > - **7** is the number of hits
> > - **20** is the number of bases taken

So, that's what it looks like. I tried to start the function and the program actually runs but I don't get the output. The cursor just blinks. Any help would be so much appreciated.

```
struct playerRecordType
{ 
    string name;
    string position;
    int number;
    int atBats;
    int hits;
    int basesTaken;
    int ranking;
    double battingAverage;
    double sluggingAverage;
};


int InputPlayerData(ifstream& inFile, playerRecordType player[MAX]);

int main(void)
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    //open the files
    inFile.open("SoftballData.txt");
    outFile.open("SoftballResults.txt");

    playerRecordType player[MAX];

    int length = InputPlayerData(inFile, player);

    outFile << length;

    return 0;
}


int InputPlayerData(ifstream& inFile, playerRecordType player[])
{
     int index;

    //initialize i
    index = 0;

    //primer for the loop
    getline(inFile, player[index].name);

   //while not end-of-file to process the file data
   while(!inFile.eof())
   {
            inFile >> player[index].name >> player[index].position 
                    >> player[index].number >> player[index].atBats
                >> player[index].hits >> player[index].basesTaken;

        index++;        
   }
```

Comment: Your function `InputPlayerData()` doesn't return anything as far as we can tell...

Comment: And this: `while(!inFile.eof())` [**is wrong**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You also read the first player's name twice, which clearly isn't going to fly since the second read (in the loop) will introduce a mis-sync on your remaining data stream. That will cause your stream to fall into an error-condition, but *not* an EOF condition, and the loop will spin forever.

Comment: You need to show us more of the function (up to the ending brace `}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this:

```
while(!inFile.eof())
```

is wrong. [Read this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for why this is so.

Next, your loop body and initial entrance is incorrect. You do this:

```
//primer for the loop
getline(inFile, player[index].name);
```

in an apparent attempt to load the first player's name, then proceed in the loop body to do this:

```
inFile >> player[index].name >> player[index].position
       >> player[index].number >> player[index].atBats
       >> player[index].hits >> player[index].basesTaken;
```

Note the player's name line is read *twice*. This will throw off the remaining data of this record, with the last element, `basesTaken` attempting to extract (and fail) to pull an integer from the *second* player's name. The result is the stream will be placed in an error state, but has not yet reached EOF. Therefore, adding insult to injury the incorrect while-loop condition discussed previously will never be true, the loop will execute again, and due to the error state, fail all extractions, looping again, not yet eof, etc...

I would hazard to guess this is what you're trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct playerRecordType
{
    std::string name;
    std::string position;
    int number;
    int atBats;
    int hits;
    int basesTaken;
    int ranking;
    double battingAverage;
    double sluggingAverage;
};

inline std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, playerRecordType& player)
{
    if (std::getline(inp, player.name) &&
        std::getline(inp, player.position) &&
        (inp >> player.number >> player.atBats >> player.hits >> player.basesTaken))
    {
        if (player.atBats > 0)
        {
            player.battingAverage = static_cast<double>(player.hits)/
                                    static_cast<double>(player.atBats);
            player.sluggingAverage = static_cast<double>(player.basesTaken)/
                                     static_cast<double>(player.atBats);
        }
        else
        {
            player.battingAverage = 0;
            player.sluggingAverage = 0;
        }
    };

    return inp;
}


template<std::size_t N>
std::size_t InputPlayerData(std::istream& inp, playerRecordType (&players)[N])
{
    std::size_t x = 0;
    for (; x < N && inp >> players[x]; ++x);
    return x;
}

#define MAX (100)

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("SoftballData.txt");
    playerRecordType players[MAX];

    std::size_t length = InputPlayerData(inFile, players);
    std::cout << length << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I leave the output side of this little quest into the deep blue code as an exercise for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

like 0x499602D2 user commented - your `InputPlayerData()` method is not returning any value.

Comment: I think it does return a value, I was just jokingly referring to the fact that the rest of the function body is cut off. (BTW I didn't downvote).